# If statement through an iteration, error: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Hello I am trying to use the function if through an iteration of excel cells. However I get the error 'float'(w_s) object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I am trying to search trough the values in 'w_s' all the values that are in the range 10-11. Can anyone suggest me any change in my code?

```
import openpyxl
import numpy

import os
os.system('cd c:\Code')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('SPLtest.xlsx')
turbine_data = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Turbinedata')
windspeed = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SPLvalues')


for row in range(2, windspeed.max_row+1):
    w_s = windspeed['A' + str(row)].value
for value in range(w_s):
    if value in numpy.arange(10.00,11.00,0.01) :
        print('107')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: `range(w_s)` => `range(int(w_s))` that will fix the error, but I think that's not what you want to achieve

Comment: akso; os.system('cd c:\Code') achieves nothing

Comment: Sorry, but without your data, nothing can really be done to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you extract the data from the excel sheet, they become floats. The range function only accepts ints, as it doesn’t make sense to have non-integral indices. Just say something like

```
for value in range(int(w_s)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems with your script, but one change you want is `np.linspace` not `np.arange`, assuming you want to iterate through something that looks like `[10.00, 10.01, 10.02, ..., 10.98, 10.99, 11.00]`.

So you want to do:

```
if value in numpy.linspace(start=10,stop=11,num=101) :
    print('107')
else:
    print('no')
```

`np.linspace` will give you `num` linearly spaced values between `start` and `stop` (inclusive).